# Parameter plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

In the Jenkin Job, looking for parameter plugin which will have three option with radio buttons. If we click on the radio button, we need to get the text box.

Depending upon the selection of the radio button, listing of other options varies. Is there any plugin in Jenkin to achieve this.

Comment: If this is the correct answer (which it most certainly is, as it does exactly what you're asking), please 'accept' the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am looking for this plugin. This helped me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.  Please indicate it's the answer by selecting the green checkmark next to the question.  Thanks.